# How do I tell Google that the supposedly suspicious activity was me?

Tags: google-account, security

Since a few months ago, all Google web apps have been telling me that they suspect suspicious activity on my account:

"Warning: Someone signed in to your account from a different location. Was it you?"

It is always one of my own computers/logins. The [Google support page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1144110?hl=en) says to click the "Yes that was me!" button. I have used this button before, but it now appears to have vanished.

Note that I do not want to disable the warning - I want it to learn about my existing logins/locations. This system is now training people to ignore the warning.